# Parse storing Object vs Storing Object Id

Tags: parse-platform

Storing object in parse gives opportunity to get a pointer relation to the other entity but does it really saves the whole object or just a pointer i mean is it better to store object as reference or foreign key or an object id (in string) form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They probably store the pointer like

```
"photo_profile":{
                   "__type": "Pointer",
                   "className": "Photos",
                   "objectId": "Tps650s7oy"
                  }
```

( if you try to export your whole data from the Parse Dashboard > Settings > Export Data, you'll receve the zip file with all the json structure of all your existing tables, then you could find something like the structure above )

Working with parse is really better to use their way to store the foreign keys, so using the Pointers. Not sure about performance improvments, but surely you retrieve a row with a pointer field inside, you can fetch that field directly with the parse methods ( on all the platform, i mean, iOS,Android,JS,...) or better, you can compose a query to obtain directy the pointed object in the resulting query ( using the include method like `query.include("follower.photo_profile");` Check the Parse documentation for more details about that.